# HighCharts: Variwide Column Stacked Chart

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Is it possible to get a Variwide Chart to stack like a Column Stacked Chart? I am wanting to Dynamically adjust the widths of the columns while keeping the columns side by side.

Total **Test1**: 50

Total **Test2**: 65

Total **Test3**: 35

Total **Test4**: 80

In this case, Test4 would take up 34%, Test2 28%, etc

[image: HighCharts]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `heatmap` chart type with multiple series and different `colsize` properties. For example:

```
series: [{
    data: [
        [0, 0, 10],
        [0, 1, 19],
        [0, 2, 8],
        [0, 3, 24],
        [0, 4, 67]
    ],
    colsize: 1,
}, {
    data: [
        [0.75, 0, 10],
        [0.75, 1, 19],
        [0.75, 2, 8],
        [0.75, 3, 24],
        [0.75, 4, 67]
    ],
    colsize: 0.5
}, {
    data: [
        [1.5, 0, 10],
        [1.5, 1, 19],
        [1.5, 2, 8],
        [1.5, 3, 24],
        [1.5, 4, 67]
    ],
    colsize: 1
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/28ytbose/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.colsize